# TableViewなどの可変のViewに制約をつける

Tags: ios, autolayout

TableViewなど内容に応じてViewのheightが変化するものにAutoLayoutに対応させるべく、
制約をつけたいが、どのように制約すればよいかわかりません。
現状、最低220pxなので[Greater than or Equal 220px]の制約をつけているが、
[inequality constraint ambiguity]の警告が発生します。動作に問題はありません。
警告をなくすにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

Comment: ひょっとして、Table Viewではなく、Table View Cellに、高さの制約をつけたい、ということなのでしょうか？

Comment: セルの数が条件によって変わるので、それに応じたテーブルビューのサイズにしたいです。

Comment: どういうふうに、したいのか、わかりませんけど。セルの数が少ない場合があって、その場合でも、縦220にしたいということでしょうか。で、セルの数が多くて、220以上（5個以上の場合）は、制約なしとしたい、ということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、そういうことです。
現在220pxから幅が500px前後まで伸縮する仕組みになっています。

Answer (score 1):

回答ではないですが。
このような場合、

I UITableView は、別のUIViewの上に、storyboardかxibの上で貼られている。
II UITableView は、UITableViewControllerとペアで使われていて、上位のContainerViewの中に含まれている。

の２つのケースがあり得ます。
　で、制約子ですが、制約子もUI部品として、outletを作ることができます。Ctrlを押しながら、マウスでドラッグする要領で。そうすると、
 IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableHeightConstraint;

というような宣言が、file's ownerのコントローラファイルに、出来ます。

詳細は、NSLayoutConstraintのクラス・リファレンスを参照する必要がありますが、
これには、@property (getter=isActive) BOOL active というプロパティがあり、
その制約子の有効・無効をコントロールすることが、可能です。

ですから、この画面のViewControllerソースのviewWillAppearの中で、セル数5個以下の場合は、制約子高さ220を有効とし、5個以上の場合は、制約子を無効にするか、別の内容にするか
すれば、どうでしょうか。
　もちろん、storyboardのframeが、どう貼られているにもよるのですが。